# Change Keyboard Layout from Windows 7 Recovery Disk

Tags: windows-7

My friend changed (I think) the keyboard layout from his Windows 7 notebook and can't log in anymore. In log screen when he types his user name he gets the wrong characters.

From Recovery Disk, I tried change the keyboard layout with regedit..

+HKEY_USERS
++.DEFAULT
+++Keyboad Layout
++++Preload

Changing "(Default)" and "1" keys to 00000416 (the code for Portuguese ABNT Keyboard Layout).

But it did not work, and when I reboot the machine the "(Default)" and "1" keys are
back to the old value.

What else can I do in this situation?

Answer (score 0):

On the log in screen, check upper left corner. There should be little icon with abbrevation of the chosen language. Click it and change language.